# How To Create Custom Select Menus with link to URL

Tags: javascript, css, custom-selectors

I have this code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

I just want to add a different URL to each option so it gets opened when clicked.
I've tried so many ways and none of them works. I don't understand Javascript and I think the options I've tried may be in conflict with this ones.

Can anyone help with this issue?
Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add value and onchange to option for example:

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did that but it didn't work :s I've tried directly on the link I've posted here and nothing changed. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Try "onclick" instead of "value".

```
<option onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">Google</option>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either :s
Could it be in conflict with the javascript?

Comment: Huh that is really strange. It works perfectly for me, then again I have a blank project with just the code I need to make it work. Try a new editor with just the code you need but instead of value use onclick and see if it works that way? Make it simple so just <select><option onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">Google</option></select>

Comment: Unfortunately it really doesn't work :( The first option you gave me works on it's own but not combined with the code in the link I've posted. My last try, if you can help, is work the way around. If I use this:

<select onchange="window.location=this.value">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.bing.com">Bing</option>
</select>

Do you know how to style the option menu list? So it doesn't use the standard menu view?

Thank you so much for your help Caleb.

Comment: Are you using seperate stylesheets or inline styling? If you are using seperate styling sheets you can give the <select> tag a class and then target that class in css. For example: html: <select class="select-class"></select> css: .select-class { font-size: 20px }. That should work. If you are using inline styling it should be the same but I highly suggest seperate stylesheets

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much for your time and help! I really appreciate it :)